# "Specified value has invalid Control characters. Parameter name: value" for a GET request with no additional headers when making a Jira API call

Tags: c#, jira, restsharp, .net-standard

I am trying to make a GET request to Jira API with basic authentication and a query parameter using RestSharp. There are no extra headers in the request.
I am able to create the request successfully when using "curl" command, but there is a "Specified value has invalid Control characters" error response when I use RestSharp.

The curl command format is:

`curl --basic -u myusername:mypassword --get https://jira.mycompany.com/rest/api/2/issue/issue-123?fields=issuelinks`

This command, executed form the same machine where the failure occurs, returns successfully with correct data.

The request I am creating from the code is the following:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient()
{
    BaseUrl = new Uri("https://jira.mycompany.com/rest/api/2/issue/issue-123"),
}

client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("myusername", "mypassword");

RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.GET)
{
    RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json,
};

request.AddParameter(new Parameter("fields", "issuelinks", ParameterType.QueryString));

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request); // This line returns the mentioned error. It is in the response.ErrorMessage property.
```

When I create the request, I get error response with message: "**Specified value has invalid Control characters. Parameter name: value**".
I have tried using different Data Formats, no DataFormat, I also tried with different Encoding when creating the client, but the result is the same.

Is there something I am missing or doing wrong? How can I create the same request with RestSharp as the one I created with curl?

PS: "Mycompany", "myusername", "mypassword" and "issue-123" are placeholder strings. Note that I am using the same values for the curl and for the RestSharp request.

Jira version: 7.4.4

Comment: Have you tried `new Parameter("paramname", ...`

Comment: Those are placeholder values, I don't want to post specifics about this request parameters, as it contains private information.

Comment: The last line throws the exception. It is the only line that has a request response in it. I cannot provide my login username and password, but I am certain they do not contain special or hidden characters. The parameter name and value are only letters with no characters. There are no other values present. And why the downvote?

Comment: How did you verify that there were no special or hidden characters?

Comment: For each string you are passing in, please check the `Length` of it - that is usually the easiest way to see whether there is a hidden character there.

Comment: Please edit your question to include **all strings**. If you are unable to do that, take all of the strings and randomise the contents into one long string and share that (only do that **after** checking the `Length` like I mention above). That way there is no risk of losing your password etc - but we get to see the characters you are using.